# Последовательное вычисление

Tags: python, массивы, циклы

Пусть имеем уравнение, например:

```
z=t0+2+x*y
```

где x и y заданные переменные величины:

```
x=np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
y=np.array([2, 4, 6, 8, 10])
t0=5
```

Нужно получить значения "z", вычисляя уравнения для каждого "x" и "y", но последовательно (т.е. первый "z" добавляем ко второму, второй к третьему и т.д.).
У меня получилось только без последовательности, для каждой пары "x" и "y", а вот дальше вышла такая абракадабра:

```
import numpy as np
t0=5
x=np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
y=np.array([2, 4, 6, 8, 10])
v = 1
for i in range(v):
    t0+=2+x*y
    print((i+1), t0)
```

Comment: А какой собственно вопрос?

Comment: цикл с ошибкой:   v =1?  значит выполнится ровно один раз 
Да и сама задача так и непонятной осталась

Comment: Вы можете привести ожидаемый на выходе результат?

Comment: В общем pinguin понял,
t0+2+x*y:
5+2+2*1=9,
9+2+2*4=19,
19+2+3*6=39
и т.д.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос:

```
import numpy as np
t0=5
x_list=np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
y_list=np.array([2, 4, 6, 8, 10])
count = 1
for x, y in zip(x_list, y_list):
    z+=t0+2+x*y
    print(count, z)
    count +=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Векторизированное решение:

```
x=np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
y=np.array([2, 4, 6, 8, 10])
t0=5
```

---

```
In [441]: t0 + np.cumsum(2 + x*y)
Out[441]: array([  9,  19,  39,  73, 125], dtype=int32)
```

[`cumsum()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) доступен также в качестве метода:

```
In [442]: t0 + (2 + x*y).cumsum()
Out[442]: array([  9,  19,  39,  73, 125], dtype=int32)
```

Answer (score 0):

По итогу имеем:

```
import numpy as np
t0=5
x_list=np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
y_list=np.array([2, 4, 6, 8, 10])
count = 1
for x, y in zip(x_list, y_list):
    t0+=2+x*y
    print(count, t0)
    count +=1
```